# Mann kendall test

Tags: trend

How to derive the variance formula in Mann kendall test in the below link.

https://vsp.pnnl.gov/help/vsample/design_trend_mann_kendall.htm

The idea for this test looks kind of random if I want to design test for testing trend of a time series how do I ensure that it is non biased and correct.

in general if I have an idea for a test based on some statistics of the data points how do I go about calculating the variance and others so that I can assign some P value to the significance of the test

Any good resources would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, to derive the variance of some statistic, you rely on [properties of variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties),  combined with other facts, depending on the specific situation. However, you don't get a p-value just by calculating a variance, unless you're relying on some large-sample approximation. It's essentially a tau-b-statistic, its distribution is discrete. Are you after a proof for the continuous version, or the one for the case with ties?

Comment: There's a derivation for both cases of the tau statistic [here](http://fisher.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/aim/vita/ps/kendall.pdf), from which it should be straightforward to extend to the trend test.

Comment: I was thinking about how to develop tests yourself and measure the statistical significant of the phenomenon that. Is there a resource which could guide me through this.